# The chat image upload "from the web" is broken for sites that use the new R3 Let's Encrypt SSL certificate

Tags: bug, chat, ssl, uploader

Let's Encrypt [expired their X3 root certificate and started issuing certificates with their R3 root certificate](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/dst-root-ca-x3-expiration-september-2021/) at the end of September.

The image uploader in chat offers an option to provide an url to an image somewhere on the web, have it fetched by a Stack Exchange server and stored in their own Imgur instance. Here is the visual for those unfamiliar with it:

[image]

I have reasons to believe the Stack Exchange server is missing the updated certificate chain for the Http Client that fetches the images. Uploads for images that are hosted on a server that uses a Let's Encrypt certificate fail consistently while images from hosts that use other TTPs work fine. For the Let's Encrypt hosted images the error is:

> Failed to upload image, please try again!

Trying again doesn't resolve the issue.

For example:

| url | LE Cert? | Result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| https://www.noaa.org/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/weather_icon.jpg | No | Works |
| https://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/styles/card_page_banner/public/about-nasa.jpg | No | Works |
| https://letsencrypt.org/images/sponsors/small/cisco-logo.png | Yes | Error |
| https://cataas.com/cat | Yes | Error |

Specially that last one is mission critical for [Kenny](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/9026636#9026636) so it can serve Cat pictures again.

It ceased to do so on September, 29th.

Can you look into this, verify my assumption of how the black-box works and when confirmed update the certificate chain. I would love to see all "from the web" uploads work again, not just for the hosts that have the funds to buy incredible expensive certificates ...